# Get public url for object uploaded on cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded a pdf file on cloud storage. But when i access url https://storage.cloud.google.com/[BUCKET]/[FILE].jpg i am redirected to google signin page. Is there any way to get a public url which gives direct access to file and doesnt have CORS issues.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was silly mistake.
Use

```
storage.googleapis.com/<bucketName>/<fileName>
```

instead of

```
storage.cloud.google .com/<bucketName>/<fileName>
```

Comment: Good job on finding the resolution to your issue. As soon as you are able to, please mark this question as solved to give it more visibility.

Comment: can anyone explain wtf is going on

Comment: @DarrenZou what is the issue?

Comment: ok now I figured it out, but you could clarified a little like: use:

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket Name}/{filename} 
instead of 
https://storage.cloud.google .com/{bucket Name}/{filename} 
because I was confused on what the solution was