# Download documents from the front end using a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

The system I am working on has Flutter Web on the front end and Google Cloud Functions on the backend. When a button is clicked in the front end, a Firestore Function is triggered. The output is a PDF whose signed URL is available. I need this pdf to be downloaded in the front end. Flutter Web cannot access storage.

I tried these methods

1. Using Flask and sending pdf as a response to a HTTP trigger,
2. Generating the signed URL, storing the URL in Cloud Firestore and reading the URL from front end.

Can it be done any other way?

**Updated**

1. Flask was not reliable. It was not downloading the pdf in the front end sometimes.
2. Since the signed URL's are valid for a maximum of 7days, regenerating the URL of 10000+ documents every 7days is not efficient.

Comment: What didn't work with those methods? Edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 2):

> Flutter Web cannot access storage.

That's not really true.  You can generate a URL for content in Cloud Storage, and use that to provide a link to the content to download.  I suggest reading:

- [How to reference Google Cloud Storage image with "img src" (link direct to the image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485102/how-to-reference-google-cloud-storage-image-with-img-src-link-direct-to-the-i)
- [Get public url for object uploaded on cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259932/get-public-url-for-object-uploaded-on-cloud-storage)

You can also send the content to the client via a Cloud Function or other endpoint by writing backend code to read the file and send it as a response.

If you're having a specific problem with any of these solutions, post a new question that describes in detail the code you haven't that isn't working the way you expect.  You're likely just doing something wrong, but we can't see what it is here.